# Spring Data Rest json-patch+json on collection item with index greater than 9

Tags: java, spring-data-rest, json-patch

The entity Parent has a collection of Item objects.

Whenever I try to run a json-patch+json request that contains an operation against a collection item with an index greater than 9 Spring throws the following exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 10 found for type Item! Traversed path: Parent.collection.

the URL is `"/Parent/1"`
the request body:

```
[
    {
      "op":"replace",
      "path":"/collection/10/property",
      "value":"100"
    }
]
```

Exactly the same request with an index less than 10 works just fine:

```
[
    {
      "op":"replace",
      "path":"/collection/9/property",
      "value":"100"
    }
]
```

Is it a spring data rest bug?

Comment: Can you provide particular example of json for Parent entity with collection of items? Are you sure collection contains more than 10 elements?

Comment: Yes absolutely sure

Comment: @N.Metlitski, your first item should be referenced as "path":"/collection/0/property", second as "path":"/collection/1/property", and 10th as "path":"/collection/9/property". There is no 11th element which can be referenced by "path":"/collection/10/property", and that's what your exception is about

Comment: I won't provide any examples - the problem is described clear enough. And there is a correct answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There was an issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1274) in Spring Data Rest project that [has recently been fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/88b73de3b74d6dfd7cdd3d7d3c010a16356053ee#diff-ea0c8d1782cfe7739519d74d30a5126cR453) (on the 8th of August 2018) in the following releases:

> [org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:3.1.0.RC2](https://spring.io/blog/2018/08/20/spring-data-lovelace-rc2-available)
>   [org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.6.15.RELEASE](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/10/spring-data-ingalls-sr15-and-kay-sr10-released)
>   [org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:3.0.10.RELEASE](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/10/spring-data-ingalls-sr15-and-kay-sr10-released)

If you use Spring Boot 2.1.x you can update your spring-data-rest-webmvc artifact version. The easiest way to do so is by setting the spring-data-releasetrain.version property to Lovelace-RC2 in your pom:

```
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Lovelace-RC2</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
```

If you use Spring Boot 2.0.x:

```
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Kay-SR10</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
```

If you use Spring Boot 1.5.x:

```
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Ingalls-SR15</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
```

As an alternative, you can update the Spring Boot version itself to the versions that already use corresponding Spring Data Rest releases:

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.0.M2        (Lovelace-RC2)

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.5.RELEASE   (Kay-SR10)

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.16.RELEASE  (Ingalls-SR15)